# VS 2010 doesnt obey working directory with Console Applications

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, console-application

I am using Visual Studio C# 2010 Express and I created a Console Application.

I want this to run in a certain directory so I go to the project's properties and in the Debug-Tab i change the working directory.

But when i debug the application it is never run there, but always in the project directory/bin/Debug.

I also tried to change the output directory under the Build-Tab but it is also not obeyed. (The binary is not copied there but always in /projectdirectory/bin/Debug)

edit: I should not the following: in the same solution i have other projects (Class Libraries and Windows Forms Applications), which actually respect the settings for Working Directory and Output Path. It just seems to be Console Applications.

Comment: You're sure you're actually debugging, not just running? (The latter would use the Release config.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: WAT? Run without debugger still runs under the 'Debug' profile.

Comment: the configuration is set to "Debug" and "Any CPU", but i have tried other configurations and have the same problem.

Comment: @clamp: You would need to change the output directory, not the working directory.

Comment: Hard to come up with an explanation for this.  Other than having more than one project in your solution and setting the Debug properties for the wrong one.

Comment: @leppie as i have said, i tried both but without success.

Comment: @leppie: Not in Express, from what I remember - at least by default. In the default install, you don't get to choose a build configuration. At least from what I remember - I'm not sure I've got Express installed on anything right now...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Ahh, I recall something like that. :) Edit: I dont see any such limitation in VSExpress (for Desktop) 2012.

Answer (score 3):

Working directory is what [GetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx) returns. Similar to `cd` in command prompt.

Working directory impacts what relative file path are relative too - i.e. opening "myFile.txt" (no file path) will search for file in "working directory" as base path if one specified in debug dialog or "output path" otherwise. You change working directory all the time while in command prompt: `cd c:\temp & findstr test *.txt" will run`findstr` with working directory "c:\temp" but will not change location of findstr.

Binary is placed in output path and not related what current working directory is.

Comment: thanks, i looked at GetCurrentDirectory() and it indeed returns what i have set in Working Directory. However the binary is not in the place that i have set in Output Path.

Comment: @clamp: Post a screenshot of the properties page where you have set it.